# Hashicorp Vault -- Create Auth Tokens Only, Don't read secrets

Tags: linux, hashicorp-vault

I'm using Hashicorp Vault:

https://www.vaultproject.io/

I want a user that can create new users, but can't read their secrets.

Would I just create a policy like:

```
path "sys/auth/token/*" {
  policy = "write"
}
```

since all policies are set to deny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the incorrect way to use Vault. These were my errors:

- Trying to store user passwords. For me, it looks better to handle platform passwords, like the integrated temporary postgre credentials.
- Trying to remove any trace of authentication keys on the server. If Vault users were going to be created automatically, Vault credentials will need to exist somewhere, either in a script or file with proper permissions.
- Trying to mitigate a rooted server. If someone has root access, there are larger problems than that. Encryption can mitigate data leaks, like a database dump. Data leaks if root access has been compromised in my case must be accepted. It's best to focus on not getting rooted.

Comment: // , Why do you think Vault would be unsuited to storing user passwords? I am considering whether to use it for this purpose.

Comment: I was trying to mitigate a rooted server. If that happens, there are bigger problems. Instead of encrypting and then trying to decrypt, which I needed for an API aggregation application, it will be better to hash, or use an identity provider and don't store passwords at all.